# Hawtio to monitor camel with Websphere MQ

Tags: apache-camel, monitoring, hawtio

we're looking for a tool to monitor our apache camel web apps. We have to use Websphere MQ. Does hawtio support WAS MQ? We haven't found any documentation about that.

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hawtio has no plugin/support for WebSphere MQ as a message broker. However hawtio as a web console can be deploy and run on IBM platforms such as WebSphere App Server. The other plugins for Camel, JMX, and so on works on WebSphere.

It is possible to build custom plugins for hawtio so someone can step up and build a WebSphere MQ plugin.